# Tungsten wattage vs resistive wattage for Smart WiFi outlets?

Tags: receptacle, circuit-breaker, air-conditioning, wifi

What is the difference between both of them? There was a post similar to my question, but there was no answer about resistive wattage.

I want to buy a wifi outlet and I need to make sure it doesn't burn like my last one when I plugged it to my AC.
I saw this new outlet.
The ratings on the outlets are:
15A / 1875W Resistive
5A/ 625W Tungsten
125V/60Hz

my Air Conditionner ratings are:
8.4 A
SCE/EER 9.4
WATTS 851
BTU 8 000

Last time my outlet stopped working but it was 10Amps, will this 15Amps one work?

[image: Link to my AC ratings]

[image: Link to the outlet ratings]

[image: Picture of the outlet - Front view]

Comment: a) Can you add a link or model # for this new outlet? b) tungsten == incandescent bulbs, which is (AFAIK) basically a resistive load. An air conditioner is a motor - very different type of load. I'd be skeptical about putting that on anything but an ordinary receptacle. c) Why do you need WiFi to control your air conditioner?

Comment: What are the WiFi switch's **motor** ratings?  If that's not listed, does it state a **ballast** rating? Can you link the product?  (Switch)?  You can [edit] your question to add that info.

Comment: @manassehkatz: a) I've added pics, b) refer to a, c) so I can turn on the AC before I arrive home and it's cold in during summer time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Tungsten loads have inrush issues resistive loads don't

Tungsten (incandescent/filament) light bulbs have a *positive temperature coefficient of resistance*.  This means that as the bulb heats up during operation, its resistance increases, and thus the current drawn by the bulb decreases.  This *inrush current* when turning on a cold bulb can be a significant multiple above and beyond the steady-state load, and thus requires the relay contacts to be *derated* from their resistive load handling capabilities in order to avoid excessive arc wear/damage to the contacts.

### Furthermore, air conditioners are a whole another animal

Your air conditioner is *neither* a tungsten *nor* a resistive load, though.  Since it uses an AC electric motor to run the internal compressor, it is a *motor* load with a very *inductive* characteristic.  This also means it's quite heavy on the inrush current as well, with a typical AC motor having a *locked rotor* starting current several times that of its full running current, and thus requires a different rating for the control switch as well.  This rating is usually given in terms of the horsepower of the largest motor that the device can safely control, so it is often called a *horsepower rating* as a result.

Furthermore, air conditioners have special properties that weigh against controlling them remotely by pulling their plug out.  In particular, this can defeat protection systems in the air conditioner that prevent it from *short cycling*, and for heat pumps, this can be a more serious issue yet due to loss of power to key accessories, such as *crankcase heaters*.

As a result, it's generally considered Not A Good Idea to use a switched outlet to control an air conditioner.  You are better off finding a way to hack the controls to do what you want, so that they can handle situations like short-cycling properly; furthermore, since your outlet lacks a horsepower rating, it's not rated to control any sort of motor load to begin with, which makes using it to control this an extra-bad idea.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I've added pics of the outlet if it can help answer my questions about the specs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using BN-LINK wifi controlled outlaets for over 2 years for my both AC: Friedrich Thru-the-Wall 12000 BTU and portable hOmeLabs | 14000 BTU Portable Air Conditioner (new CEC 10000 BTU). No any problems at all.Parameters of wifi oulets[image] see in attachment.

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot closer to suitable, as long as your AC compressor is under 1/2HP...still need to be careful not to short-cycle the AC but for "turn it on and leave it on for a while when you're on vacation", it'd be at least in the ballpark